# How can i display only month on click of datepicker in WPF xaml

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datepicker, calendar

How can i display only month of datepicker in wpf

[date picker image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LDPN.png)

Comment: Why not use just a Calendar instead of a DatePicker control?  Calendar has a DisplayMode property where you can set it to decade, year, or month.  DatePicker doesn't have this capability unless you override its ControlTemplate, which is more time-consuming.

Comment: I need something like Textbox, when click on it, i need to get a dropdown with all months.